# Could not load type IOfficeAddInEntryPoint from assembly

Tags: .net-3.5

I am trying out building a word addin in visual studio 2008 with the .net 3.5 sp1 framework.

I am making a new project for a new word addin.

I am debugging/releasing that project and running it.

I am using microsoft office 2007.

I have installed interops for 2007.

I have installed VTSO 3.0 with sp1.

When I run, office loads up fine.  The addin appears to have installed into word.  However, I get the following exception message popping up:

*** error is as follows:

Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created.

******* *Exception Text* *********
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.IOfficeAddInEntryPoint' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

---

I have no idea what to do about this.

I have checked the project references for the project I have just built.

I can see in the Microsoft.Office.Tools.v9.0 reference, 'IOfficeAddInEntryPoint' does not exist.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  What else do I need?

I have tried removes and reinstalls of the following:

VSTO and its sp1
interops
.net 3.5 framework

Do I need to do something else?  I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have read something that suggests that removing the interops is a bad idea.  An uninstall doc said the following:

1. After installing the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies as a part of the setup of a managed code solution, you should not uninstall the redistributable.  Doing so may remove the PIA’s even if another managed code solution which installed the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies is installed.  Multiple installations of the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies are not possible, therefore, removing the redistributable will not take into account other managed code solutions that are using the included PIA’s.  Removal of the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies should be an end user action from Control Panel/Add Remove Programs.
2. Uninstalling the Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies after uninstalling the .NET framework will leave the PIA’s on the hard disk in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Is this part of my problem?  Any recommendations for how to clean this up if so?

Comment: I may have just figured the answer out.  I installed the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime with vstor_redist.exe

Comment: installing vsto4 tools appears to fix the interop assemblies, they've increased in size from 693kb to 4.73mb and word addins work again.

Comment: I am almost certain that this is what happens.  You can even uninstall vstor and the interop assemblies will remain the same.